# Proper way for Repainting JComponent

Tags: java, repaint, jcomponent

So, I've taken an AP class on java, and in the class, we never really went over `repaint()`, and how to properly use it. I've also searched through the internet, and I personally have not found any answers on the standard way of calling `repaint()`. Are we supposed to call the `repaint()` method from the `main` class like the following?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RepaintExample{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JComponent component = new JComponent();
        frame.add(component);
        frame.repaint();
    }

}
```

Or would I call the `JComponent.repaint()` Like this

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RepaintExample{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JComponent component = new JComponent();
        frame.add(component);
        component.repaint();
    }

}
```

Or, are both approaches wrong, and `JComponent.repaint()` should be called from the `paintComponent` as shown here:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComponentRepaintExample extends JComponent{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        //Draw stuff
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            //Draw stuff
            this.repaint();
        }
    }

}
```

It is quite possible that all three approaches are wrong. Any help figuring out how to properly use the `repaint()` method is appreciated. The whole topic is very shrouded to me, so I apologize if any terminology I use is incorrect. All thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think you need to call repaint()?

The repaint() method is invoked by a Swing component automatically when a property of the component is changed.

For example if you have a JLabel and you invoke `setText(...)` or `setIcon(...)`, then those methods will automatically invoke repaint().

You would NEVER invoke repaint() from a painting method.

If you are doing custom painting, then your code should be structured like any other Swing component. That is you create getter/setter methods for your custom components to change properties of the component. In the setter method you invoke repaint().